# Canonical name redirects in Godaddy?

Tags: iis, redirect, http-status-code-301, hostname, canonical-link

I have a website "mywebsite.com" and I would like to do a 301 redirect of "http://mywebsite.com" to "http://www.mywebsite.com" (for the usual SEO purposes).

I am running IIS7, however there is an ISA server firewall in front of the site, which seems (as per this article, though his solution did not work for me -- http://mrvirtual.de/2009/07/04/url-rewrite-through-isa-server-ends-in-a-loop/) to be causing the rewrite rule to go into an infinite redirect loop.

DNS is being managed by Godaddy (TotalDNS). Is there a way to configure DNS, or domain forwarding, so that I can accomplish the redirect prior to reaching the ISA firewall / IIS? This seems easier (if possible), than trying to track down and fix the ISA, IIS problem (though if someone has a solution for that, I'll take it).

Comment: I received a response from Godaddy: 

    With the DNS configuration you are using it is not possible to forward the domain though the DNS. You may want to consider the 301 re-direct. 

So, I can't do it through Godaddy DNS, say they.

Comment: My current kludge to get around the ISA problem, which is working but which causes me aesthetic grief, is to to use IIS 7 url rewriting to redirect http://mywebsite.com to another domain, http://mywebsite.info, but http://mywebsite.info redirects to http://www.mywebsite.com. Two redirects where there should be one.

Comment: I retract my statement that the article above did not solve the problem. I just didn't try enough variations.

In the ISA server policies, "To" tab, "This rule applies to this published website" textbox, I changed the field from www.mywebsite.com -- which is how it is listed in IIS) to just be MyWebsite... it appears that I could make this any text string, as long as it is not the name of the actual site as used in the redirect (both mysite.com & www.mysite.com caused the infinite loop).

Changed it as described above and problem solved. Thanks for the nudge mcandre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First result for "IIS redirect to www":

http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/domain.asp

Comment: This did not work for me. It may be the configuration setting being from an earlier IIS version -- in IIS 7 when you set the redirect it updates the website's web.config, and as the example has the redirected site pointing to the same folder it makes the www. site redirect to itself. Thus another endless redirect loop. 

Entertainingly however, it happens that xoc.net is my brother's website. Too bad he never calls me, or I'd tell him to update his examples! ;-)

Comment: Spoke to my brother and he helped me sort it out. Thanks for reminding me about old what's his name!

The solution he has on his site would have worked without the ISA server issue, with the caveat that you might need to have it not point to the same project that you are redirecting to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS7 and you're using .Net 3.5 (at a minimum) the quickest way IMHO is to just quickly add this to your web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Note: in this example its from a non www url to a www url

Hope this helps buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I retract my statement that the article above did not solve the problem. I just didn't try enough variations. In the ISA server policies, "To" tab, "This rule applies to this published website" textbox, I changed the field from www.mywebsite.com -- which is how it is listed in IIS) to just be MyWebsite... it appears that I could make this any text string, as long as it is not the name of the actual site as used in the redirect (both mysite.com & www.mysite.com caused the infinite loop). Changed it as described above and problem solved. Thanks for the nudge mcandre. – Gene 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on ASP NET, then there is a simple fix that you can apply by using the application_beginrequest event of the global asax

Here is a detailed explanation
http://www.xaviermorera.com/2010/01/fix-canonical-redirect-issue-on-asp-net-in-a-shared-host-rackspacecloud/

Answer (score 0):

Why do try complex things? Just try the below code with the filename .htacces and upload in the root folder of your website host server (public_html).

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://example.com/" [R=301,L]

Comment: users question is about IIS which means they are on windows not .htacces file