# Redirect from http://sitename.com to http://www.sitename.com

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I am using ASP.NET 4. I want to do a 301 redirect from http://sitename.com to http://www.sitename.com.

What's the best way (and optional ways) to do it?

My site is also getting indexed on the ip address. How can I stop that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a simple check in the `Page_Load`:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serverName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]); 
        string filePath = Request.FilePath;
        if (!serverName.ToLower().StartsWith("www.")) 
            serverName = "www." + serverName; 
        Response.Redirect("http://" + serverName + filePath); 
    }
```

Or you could add the following to the htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Replacing `domain.com` and `http://www.domain.com` with your domain.

Comment: Response.Redirect issues a 302 redirect, not a 301 redirect. The .htaccess option would only work with Apache, not IIS.

Comment: You are correct of course...Teach me for skim reading what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the 301 redirect at the IIS level, see this blog posting: [SEO Canonical URLs And 301 Redirects In Windows IIS 6, IIS 7](http://www.barrywise.com/2008/10/seo-canonical-urls-and-301-redirects-in-windows-iis-6-iis-7/)

To stop the site being indexed on the IP address, [configure the "site" in IIS to have a host name](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx), don't leave it blank.

Comment: I do not have much control over IIS. Can you suggest me an alternative

Comment: If you're using IIS7 and the hosting provider gives you the correct permissions you can configure this in your Web.config file, in the system.webServer section.

Comment: yes but the url rewrite module needs to be installed on the server and it looks like it isn't. That's why I need an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DNS provider it may be possible for them to set up redirects usually called something like web forwards, web alias or web redirects. Just make sure it's a 301 not a frameset.

Related questions: [Canonical name redirects in Godaddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290053/canonical-name-redirects-in-godaddy)

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="Redirect to www">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.serdardemir.net/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

you can use url rewrite add this  rule to rules tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

This code worked me. Add this in rules section of your web.config file